# $window.addEventListener is working only first time, but next time on wards not working through $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

`$window.addEventListener` is working only first time, next time on wards not working whenever network status change in angularjs with worklight 8

```
app.factory('onlineStatus', function($window, $rootScope) {
    var onlineStatus = {};

    onlineStatus.onLine = navigator.onLine;

    onlineStatus.isOnline = function() {
      return onlineStatus.onLine;
    };

    $window.addEventListener("online", function() {
      onlineStatus.onLine = true;
      $rootScope.$digest();
    }, true);

    $window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
      onlineStatus.onLine = false;
      $rootScope.$digest();
    }, true);

    return onlineStatus;
});
```

```
$scope.onlineStatus = onlineStatus;
$scope.$watch('onlineStatus.isOnline()', function(online) {
    $scope.netStatus = online ? 'online' : 'offline';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the factory:

```
app.factory('onlineStatus', function($window, $rootScope) {
    var onlineStatus = {};

    onlineStatus.onLine = $window.navigator.onLine;

    onlineStatus.isOnline = function() {
        return $window.navigator.onLine;
    };

    $window.addEventListener("online offline", function() {
      onlineStatus.onLine = $window.navigator.onLine;
      $rootScope.$broadcast("onlineStatus", $window.navigator.onLine);
      $rootScope.$digest();
    }, false);

    return onlineStatus;
});
```

Keep in mind that `navigator.onLine` is a getter property (not a value property). Also it bubbles up to window from document.body. It is not appropriate to use capture phase for the event listener.

Instead of adding a watcher, subscribe to the scope event:

```
$scope.$on('onlineStatus', function(ev, online) {
    $scope.netStatus = online ? 'online' : 'offline';
});
```

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - Navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)
- [MDN Web API Reference - Document.ononline property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/ononline)